# Should pre-intervention outcome variable Y0 be excluded from counterfactual model based on causal diagram?

Tags: panel-data, mediation, confounding, counterfactuals, collider

Based on the causal diagram below, where:

- Y1 is the outcome in the post-intervention period,
- Y0 is the pre-intervention outcome,
- X is a Yes/No healthcare intervention, and
- Z1 & Z2 represent various confounder variables (diagnoses, geography, etc.).

Shouldn't Y0 be excluded from the counterfactual model estimating the effect of X on Y1 given it is both a collider and mediator variable?

Is there any reason not to exclude Y0 from the study?

[image]

Comment: Are the Zs observed?

Comment: @dimitriy Yes they are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$Y_0$ is not a mediator; it is a confounder. You must adjust for it. If $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ were not observed, this would induce what's sometimes called "butterfly bias"; but if you can adjust for them, then all confounding is removed. The sole minimally sufficient adjustment set is $Y_0$, $Z_1$, and $Z_2$.

Comment: (+1) Wouldn't also be sensible to point out that $Y_0$ is not a mediator as there is no mediated effect between the independent variable $X$ causing $Y_0$ causing the dependent variable $Y_1$?

Comment: Thanks Noah - my initial thoughts were Y0 is a mediator lying on the paths between Z1, Z2, and Y1. And Y0 could also be a collider since two causal arrows from Z1 and Z2 converge on Y0.

Comment: If the X <- Y0 -> Y1 path didn't exist, then Y0 would be a collider that ought to be excluded since it blocks the Y1 <- Z2 -> Y0 <- Z1 -> X path. But the Y1 <- Y0 -> X path complicates things.

Comment: If you adjust for $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, then even if $Y_0$ is a collider and not a confounder, adjusting for it would not bias the treatment effect. Because it would not open any backdoor paths. Instead of thinking about classifying each variable into a causal "type", think about its role in the DAG and the consequences of adjusting for it while adjusting for others. Yes $Y_0$ is a mediator and a collider, but adjusting for it is necessary. The rule "don't adjust for colliders" is too coarse to apply to this more complicated scenario.

Comment: Think I see - if Y0 is a collider & not a confounder, conditioning on Y0 opens the Y1 <- Z2 -> Y0 <- Z1 -> X backdoor path, but controlling for Z1 then closes the path right?

Comment: Another issue we're struggling with at work are regression to the mean effects when including pre-intervention variables like Y0 in our model. It's not really a "causal" effect of Y0 on Y1, but a real concern when the Y0 distributions are significantly different in the treatment and control populations. Maybe a separate question!

Comment: That's correct. For your second question, check out [this article](https://osf.io/5zdme).