# In covariate-specific effect - $P(Y=y|do(X=x),Z=z)$ - is $Z=z$ pre- or post-treatment measure?

Tags: causality, dag, causal-diagram

*Causal Inference In Statistics* by *Pearl*, section 3.5, page 70 clearly mentions that -

> This effect, written $P(Y=y|do(X=x),Z=z)$, measures the distribution
> of $Y$ in a subset of the population for which $Z$ achieves the value
> $z$ after the intervention.

In that context Rule 2 says -

> $P(Y=y|do(X=x),Z=z)$
>  $= \sum_s {P(Y=y|X=x,S=s,Z=z)P(S=s|Z=z)}$

where $S \cup Z$ satisfies the backdoor criterion.

**Query: Is $Z=z$ in the second expression pre- or post-intervention measure?**

**Note:** In subsequent section where the effect of conditional intervention is evaluated, it says -

> $P(Y=y|do(X=g(Z)))$
> $=\sum_z{P(Y=y|do(X=g(Z)),Z=z)P(Z=z|do(X=g(Z)))}$
> $=\sum_z{P(Y=y|do(X=g(z)),Z=z)P(Z=z)}$
> The equality $P(Z=z|do(X=g(Z)))=P(Z=z)$ stems, of course, from the fact that $Z$
> occurs before $X$; hence any control exerted on $X$ can have no effect
> on the distribution of $Z$.

Here it seems that $Z=z$ is a pre-intervention measure. Hence, in the above sections, when is $Z-z$ a pre-intervention measure and when is it a post-intervention measure?

Comment: It's pre-intervention if either $Z\to X$ or there are a series of arrows from $Z$ to $X.$ It's post-intervention if either $X\to Z$ or there are a series of arrows from $X$ to $Z.$

Comment: @AdrianKeister could you please provide some reference for the above claim? Besides, in $P(Y=y|do(X=x),Z=z)$, $Z=z$ may be post-intervention measure. But in the RHS expression $\sum_s {P(Y=y|X=x,S=s,Z=z)P(S=s|Z=z)}$, $Z=z$ needs to be observational/pre-intervention correct (as it's just a theoretically simulated intervention and we do not have access to post-intervention data)?

Comment: Alas, I don't have a reference for it. I heard this concept in a presentation that was utilizing causality. But this idea makes sense: for something to be pre-intervention, it must be *before* $X;$ and for it to have any interest, it must be causally related to $X.$ Hence, the arrows go into $X$. You see it in passing here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/598107/should-pre-intervention-outcome-variable-y0-be-excluded-from-counterfactual-mode